# How do I make PhpED preserve line endings/breaks?

Tags: line-breaks, file-format, phped

Professionally I work with NuSphere PhpED on a Windows computer. Whenever I open a file from an existing project and save it the IDE automatically converts all the line endings/breaks to UNIX.

This presents a problem because it means that I am unable to track my changes in SVN afterwards as it will replace the contents of the entire file instead of just the lines I have actually touched.

I have tried changing the "Default file format" settings between "Unix", "Windows" and "Autodetect"; but regardless of this setting when I open the "Save As..." dialogue "File Format:" is always listed as Unix.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and managed to overcome it?

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Comment: What version are you using? In your project settings under Project->Content, what is the default file encoding?

Answer (score 0):

It may be your *particular* NuSphere version.

On NuSphere PhpED Professional Version 14.0 (Build 14040, 64bit), when I set "Default file format" to "Windows", the "Save As" shows "File Format" of "Windows".

If I change "Default file format" to "Unix", the "Save As" shows "File Format" of "Unix".